# Android reading text files(.txt) into an array of strings

Tags: java, android, arrays, error-handling, text-files

This is the code:

```
 void CreateWordList()
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Creating Word List...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pass);
    BufferedReader lines = null;
    try {
        lines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;
        try {
            while((line = lines.readLine()) !=null)list.add(line);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            wordlist = (String[]) list.toArray();
        if (wordlist[1] == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ERROR: Word List = null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

I have a **error** at "`line = lines.readLine();`" that says "Unhandled exception of type IOException" so i surrounded it with try/catch.

And I have another **error** at "`BufferedReader lines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));`" that says "Unhandled exception type UnsupportedEncodingException" so i surrounded it with try/catch.

Now when i run the app it crashes...

What am I doing wrong ?

How can I read a text file and add each line to an array of strings ?

**PS: I have searched and found other similar questions and answers but that did not help me...**

Comment: lines.readLine() will not return null if the file is finished, it will return -1

Comment: Confused - I can't see a single try/catch in your code. I doubt that compiles. Please post your real code.

Comment: I added the try/catch after sorry i will edit the question

Comment: Now i edited the code and added the try/catch

Answer (score 0):

change  this

```
 while(true){
 line = lines.readLine();
```

to this

```
 while((line = lines.readLine()) !=null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    void CreateWordList()throws IOException{
...}
```